# How to make a category page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have few categories in the wordpress blog which i list them by using

```
<?php wp_list_categories('exclude=4,7&title_li='); ?>
```

It returns a list with all categories which are linked like in format `http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat1/`

when i click them i get a 404.

I want to make a template for categories which dynamically sets the current clicked category and return posts in the loop which have that category.

Comment: Create a file called archive.php in your theme folder. This is your new "categories" page.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: i have one,but it just has loop and the head and foot. What should i ass or configure to make it to work

Comment: you need category.php